# How to cancel AFNetworking requests if there is nothing written in search bar?

Tags: uitableview, afnetworking

I am implementing something like realtime search. For example, if I write "p", it makes a query in the server, and "pi" makes another query. So every written char makes the app do a request to server.

But, after some chars, if I start to delete immediately, because all requests are async, since there is no char in the search bar, old requests get some results and load in the table.

My code is:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
[[ApiClient sharedClient] cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"cuisines/search/"];

if(![searchText length]){
    [self.searchList removeAllObjects];
    [self.searchTableView reloadData];
}
else if([searchText length] > 0){
    if(searchBar == leftSearchBar){
        [[ApiClient sharedClient] getPath:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cuisines/search/?q=%@&locale=%@", searchText, locale] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            [self.searchList removeAllObjects];
            NSMutableArray* list = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"cuisines"];
            if(list.count > 0){
                for (id c in list) {
                    Cuisine *cuisine = [[Cuisine alloc] initWithAttributes:c];
                    [self.searchList addObject:cuisine];
                }
            }  
            [self.searchTableView reloadData];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(error.description);
        }];           
     }    
   }    
}
```

So, how can I stop the previous request when a new request is made?

EDIT:

I wrote cancel request in the beginning of texDidChange. But its same. I have a question:

Path for:

```
cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"cuisines/search/"];
```

and

```
cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"GET" path @"cuisines/search/?q=%@&locale=%@", searchText, locale] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]
```

are the same because of the root? If they are not, how can I find and cancel the request?

Answer (score 0):

When the text changes, you should check if there is already a request and cancel it using `cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:path` immediately. You already do this on line 3, but only if the text is empty. If you always do this, it will never allow 2 requests to be made simultaneously.